# Golang - local import warning in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code warns about local import but the code is still executable.
What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem like a proper import statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go doesn't have relative imports. You just can't have that.

Your main application Go file must be at the topmost location in your project repository.

Comment: Also what's with `ct` before the import path?

Comment: `ct` it's just an alias

Comment: Yes, I've also found that relative imports aren’t allowed in workspace (most commonly $GOPATH/src). But it still works, even with highlited error in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a warning this is an error.Your code is not executable you are wrong maybe running a previously compiled version.